# Recommended Document Management Systems?

Tags: document-management

I have lots picture that is taken from different books. I also have some pd file.

TOday, I'm looking for a Document Management Systemsthat can review the file and also enable to make tag.

The closest software you can use i SharePoint but it is used for large company.

Do you have any recommendation?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question and give a few more details: what is a "pd file" (PDF?), what OS must be supported, what do you understand by "review the file", what features should the software have (apart from review & tag)? To give you "tailored recommendations", we need to know your requirements as close as possible :)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need any special workflow, and mostly need image management + tagging support, try Evernote.

If it's not enough, write more about:

- who will be using the software
- do you need any workflow, user/group permissions etc.
- desired environment: Windows, Linux, browser
- desired integration with other systems
- planned budget